# Importing shp file into GRASS - syntax error?

Tags: grass-gis, vector, error, import

I'm just starting out learning GRASS. I am trying to import my first shapefile, and I'm getting an error message:

> ERROR: Unable to open data source

I think I'm just not entering the syntax correctly and that's where the problem is, although I suppose it might be something with the file. The file is located here on my computer: D:\Data\GRASSData\NhoodAssoc\Associations.shp.

Here are the instructions on importing I'm following: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Tips_for_Arc_users#Import_of_Shapefiles_into_GRASS.

Under 'Import of Shapefiles into GRASS' it appears that I should be able to just enter in "v.in.ogr input=associations.shp output=associations." ["input" appears to be the current syntax instead of "dsn" listed in the instructions]. But I get that error when I do.

I've also tried to use the file structure, although I'm not sure how to enter that into the suggested syntax - for example, do I need to start with "D" since that's the drive it's on?

Any idea why I'm getting this error and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The input parameter needs to be the full path to the shapefile.
So you would need:

```
v.in.ogr input="D:\Data\GRASSData\NhoodAssoc\Associations.shp" output=associations
```